# Identify an element using the text contents of a child within the element

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I have some list elements and I need to apply a style to only the last three. How can I apply a style to these three? In future versions, they may not be at the end of the list, so I prefer a version that takes advantage of the text inside a label that appears inside each one as seen below:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    //I DON'T want to select this one
    //<label>I</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    //I DON'T want to select this one
    <label>don't</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    //I DON'T want to select this one
    <label>care.</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    //I want to select this one
    <label>Label 1</label>
    //more follows...
  </li>
  <li>
    //I want to select this one
    <label>Label 2</label>
    //more follows...
  </li>
  <li>
    //I want to select this one
    <label>Label 3</label>
    //more follows...
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
$('li:has("label")')
```

to select the list items that have label elements as children. [.has()](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/): "Selects elements which contain at least one element that matches the specified selector." You could also use `$('li').has("label")` which may offer a slight performance increase.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xdCHR/)**

Comment: This is a great start! I suppose I should have mentioned that the other li elements contain labels as well. Can take this a step further and add to the selector that it should contain a certain string like "Label 1"?

Comment: You may be able to use :contains as well. http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Answer (score 0):

You can use nth-child in CSS like this:

`li:nth-child(n+3) { color: #999 }`

The n+3 syntax means that the color is applied the any list item after the first three (so in your example above with six list items, it would apply the color to the last three.